How to dump quotes while keeping protection against XSS attacks in Laravel
I have a series of user-input string fields that have to accept ' and ", and I have to present them correctly in a blade view.
I would like to know if it would be secure (and what issues can I find) if I replace the scaped quote with prime, and the escaped double quote with double prime for the presentation, this way:
{!! str_replace(['&#039;', '&quot;'], ['´', '″'], e($userInputValue)) !!}
Thank you.
PD. I do not want to use Purifier for the inputs, as I feel it heavy for my application.

The risk for attacks is when input is sent to the backend (server) not when you display something to the user. Laravel proects against XSS attacks

I think that Laravel protects you against XSS attacks only if you use {{ }} for dumping in the balde view. If you use {!! !!}, e() is not applied, so if the attack reach the DB, then the dump is not protected anymore against XSS attacks.
